# Input value not updating

Tags: jquery

UPDATE:
It looks like I need to reference the iframe first and then the item.

When I do..

```
  $('#iframestorelocator').contents().find("#location").val("Value from parent file.");
```

I now get:

> SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://fake.com" from
>   accessing a frame with origin "https://example.com".
>   Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Previous:
I am trying to update the following input but nothing seems to work.
When I try directly in the console is

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
   <label class="control-label" for="name">Location</label>
   <input class="form-control" type="text" name="location" id="location" placeholder="Street, city, zip code, or state">
</div>



//When docuemnt is ready, the value is populated
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
    $("#location").val(response.city+", "+ response.region+" "+ response.country);
}, "jsonp");

});
```

I also tried $("#location").attr("value", response.city+", "+ response.region+" "+ response.country);

Nothing seems to read or write to the input.

In the Console I tried:

```
$("#location").attr("value", "test")
```

I get:

> b (0) = $1

But if I do $("#location").val() 
After, I get undefined.

Comment: What do you get if you console log `response` inside your AJAX statement?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the full code, but you seem to have your variable `country` defined nowhere. Try setting it to `response.country`, or, as @j08691 correctly pointed out, log the response and check out the response object.

Comment: Is the server returning jsonp?

Comment: response.county was there in original code. Sorry, updated now

Comment: debug code as suggested by j08691

Comment: I get the json response. The issue does not seem to be the response, as I  can't even update it manually with $("#location").attr("value", "test")

Comment: Could you show all the code in the page?

Comment: https://www.thebusinessofbalayage.com/pages/class-locator is example. form comes from an iframe.

Comment: I checked multiple cases,most of them throwing a error log in the console. Only the case where getting 'undefined' is, when trying to get value with wrong ID. e.g. $("#locatio").val(). So you can check, DOM is available when code is running and ID is correct in your actual code.

Comment: Looks like I needed to reference the iframe first, only now I get a security issue.

Answer (score 0):

You missed response in country value. Just try the following. Hope to help, my friend :))

```
//When document is ready, the value is populated
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
    $("#location").val(response.city+", " + response.region + " " + response.country);
}, "jsonp");

});
```

Comment: If you are miss object name, you will get 'not defined' error in the console.

Comment: That was a mistype stack overflow. Sorry, it was there. Corrected now.

Comment: @user2012677: Well played, my friend :d